# Questions missing from Highest Voted Questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, sorting

Since the two "questions"

- [NSFW proposal on Area51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115732) (current votes: -42)
- [Why I am leaving StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115774) (current votes: -26)

got downvoted into an abyss lately, I was wondering which were the most downvoted questions of all time.

As it turns out, none of these two questions appear on the last page of the Highest Voted Questions, although - judging by their current votes - they should.

Proof:

- [15 per page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2033&sort=votes&pagesize=15)
- [30 per page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=1017&sort=votes&pagesize=30)
- [50 per page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=610&sort=votes&pagesize=50)
- Screenshot with `pagesize=5`:

  [image: Missing questions]

**Update:**

[Why I am leaving StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115774) got downvoted once more (current votes: -27) and now it appears on the last page.

**Update:**

[Why I am leaving StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115774) got downvoted once more (current votes: -28) and now it's gone again.

**Update:**

[Why I am leaving StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115774) got downvoted once more (current votes: -29) and it's still gone.

Comment: They don't appear in [the recently deleted list either (10k only)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=last2days). Perhaps the team stepped in.

Comment: Something is definitely not right, because the lowest voted question I know of that hasn't been deleted has a much lower score: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed

Comment: @dmckee: The questions have not been deleted. The links in my post still work.

Comment: I am investigating...

Comment: ok; found it... it was on page 3 ! I've given the system a kick while I investigate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crazy is as crazy does. This should no longer be a problem. Pure bug - although it was *tempting* to blame you personally... (just kidding).

Comment: Marc, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120204/glitch-when-sorting-questions-by-vote-count