# HALP! My snowman doesn't have a head! 

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, notifications, internet-explorer-9

Chat notifications are snowmen now. Well, most are, I should say.

In x86 IE9 on Windows 7 x64, mine is headless. Can someone please fix this egregious error? It's gruesome to look at a headless corpse of a snowman every time I get pinged in chat.

[image]

Comment: Well it *is* IE9.

Comment: +1 for the freehand `:-(`

Comment: @Shads0 Maybe if someone could answer [this](http://superuser.com/questions/368020/sync-icloud-bookmarks-with-firefox-in-windows-7) I wouldn't be in this mess!

Comment: -1 for missing "Eeeek!"

Comment: Your spread-eagled gravatar gives me the gooch-willies (those are bad, btw).

Comment: One man's gooch-willy is another man's ooch-walla.

Comment: Wait, what the hell did I even just say?

Comment: @MarkM You said, "One man's gooch-willy is another man's ooch-walla."

Comment: Hide yo' snow kids! Hide yo' snow wife! They beheadin' errbody up in herrr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE9 was being a PITA as usual, so I disabled the snowmen there for now. I'll try to get it to work when I have the time; until then you'll have to live with a snowball.

**Update:** Found the issue; you have a snowman now. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Please fix this with great haste, else [I will boycott SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115732/nsfw-proposal-on-area51)

Comment: Please don't put too much effort into supporting IE's brokeness. We all know how little effort MS putting into supporting the relevant standards.

Comment: @Chris S: It's 2011 (hell, almost the end of 2011, 2012 is coming); you need to start having faith in Microsoft (again).

Comment: @MarkM: How about boycotting IE?  It seems like a much better cause.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I'll have faith in them when I don't need to fix my code so it works in IE.

Comment: @Rocket In case you missed it, [my boycott threat was in jest](http://i.imgur.com/0nOgv.jpg).

Comment: @MarkM: I need more coffee, err Mt. Dew =/